# Time series analysis - putting values into bins

Tags: pandas

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMDOk.png)

How can I split the values in the category_lvl2 column into bins for each different value, and find the average amount for all the values in each bin?
For example finding the average amount spent on coffee

I have already performed feature scaling on the amounts

Comment: Please dont put images here. Put the data in the question as code. Also show your attempt.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with a [MCVE] so that somebody can just copy and paste your code and improves from what you started with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby()` method and provide the groups you get with `pd.cut()`. The example below bins the data into 10 categories by sepal_length column. Then those categories are used to groupby the iris df. You could also bin with a variable and get the mean of another one with groupby.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

bins = pd.cut(iris.sepal_length, 10)
iris.groupby(bins).sepal_length.mean()
```